# C# application is doubling the path in mono on Ubuntu, not in windows

Tags: c#, path, mono, ubuntu-12.04

Hi first time using stackoverflow. I apologize in advance if I did something wrong. The below code works perfectly in windows in regards to returning the path, however in Ubuntu using mono 2.10.8.1

the path should be `/home/procon/Plugins/BF3/filename.cfg`

instead it's looking for the file at `/home/procon/home/procon/Plugins/BF3/filename.cfg`

I have narrowed down the issue to this code below, and I've tried changing Application.ExecutablePath to Environment.CurrentDirectory and it's still returning the wrong path. Any ideas?

```
public static String makeRelativePath(String file)
    {
        String exe_path = Directory.GetParent(Application.ExecutablePath).FullName;
        String dll_path = Directory.GetParent(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).FullName;

        String rel_path = dll_path.Replace(exe_path, "");
        rel_path = Path.Combine(rel_path.Trim(new char[] { Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar }), file);
        return rel_path;
    }
```

Comment: What are the values of `exe_path` and `dll_path` ?

Comment: Add console debug print, printing all the string variables there (including `file` parameter, and print `rel_path` twice, both after initializing it, and after modifying it), and add output to question for both platforms.